# jquery toggle div if user clicks on outer/parent div?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a piece of jquery to toggle my div 'float_column3' when a user clicks on my parent div 'header'.

I have multiple occurrences of the divs 'float_column3' and 'header' so I am trying to use this parent so that it only shows the 'float_column3' div for the parent div 'header' which the user clicks on.

```
    <div class="align"><p class="header">Access Platforms</p>

     <div class="float_column3">
     {SHOW WHEN USER CLICKS PARENT DIV 'HEADER'}
     </div>

    </div>

   <div class="align"><p class="header">Access Platforms</p>

     <div class="float_column3">
     {SHOW WHEN USER CLICKS PARENT DIV 'HEADER'}
     </div>

    </div>

   <div class="align"><p class="header">Access Platforms</p>

     <div class="float_column3">
     {SHOW WHEN USER CLICKS PARENT DIV 'HEADER'}
     </div>

    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>

$(".header").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().next('.float_column3').toggle();


});

</script>
```

My 'float_column3' div has a css display:none and should toggle/show when the user clicks 'header' then toggle again/hide when the user clicks it again.

my problem is this code is not executing at all. Can someone please show me where im going wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.float_column3` is sibling of clicked element and not of its parent. Use:

```
$(".header").click(function(){
 $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: fantastic. thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as it let's me. appreciate the help.

Comment: is there any way I can auto close the float_column3 div which is open when a user clicks onto another one?

Comment: use `$(".header").click(function(){
 $(this).next().toggle();
$('.float_column3').not($(this).next()).hide()
});`

Answer (score 0):

change `next` to `find`:

```
 $(this).parent().find('.float_column3').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".header").click(function () {
         jQuery(".float_column3").toggle();
    });
});
```

as of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5wdrs59/)